# when trying to add a hair particle system blender crashes

Tags: particles, hair

Hi I'm not sure if this is the correct forum so I apologise if it isn't. If not would someone be able to point me in the correct direction.
I've been trying to add a hair particle system. I can add a particle system with no issue, but when I try to change it to a hair system blender crashes. I had been following a 'Default Cube' Tutorial on YouTube, for a golf ball in grass.I have also tried adding a hair particle system in a new blend file and on different primitives, eg plane, UV sphere. I have also tried reducing the count down to 100 but it still crashes. I am in object mode and viewport display.

I have tried this in Blender 2.92, swell as 2.93 Alpha, and it is just the same.I have also reinstalled 2.92 but again the issue remains

I am using a 2015 iMac running MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3
specs are

Processor: 3.3 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5
Memory: 32 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
Graphics: AMD Radeon R9 M290 2 GB

I don't think there is much point in uploading a sample blend file as it does it when I just start a new file, the same happens with older blend files.

Below is a link to my google drive with a word doc of the crash report

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EX1UbJykos1FgmFKcqhDn5_kFEvBlF4f/view?usp=sharing

EDIT

The blend file I was working on when I first noticed the issue. Though this issue still happens no matter what the blend file, even a brand new one

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D8OmXeA7rTaHqKrzn8qSyTjE5Ky2D2SC/view?usp=sharing

Many thanks

Simon

Comment: and i believe uploading your blend file would help....

Comment: do I just upload it to my google drive and send the link?
Should I upload the one I was using to follow the tutorial? as it happens in literally any blend file I open

Comment: added a link to the blend file in the original post

Comment: i have a macbook too, but a newer one. I have no problems with your blend file - and no problems adding particle system and changing problems. So my only guess...you could probably restart your mac and try again. it should work. on my older macbooks it worked too, Maybe you should turn on EEVEE as long as you are changing properties. Change to cycles if you are rendering....

Comment: Thanks, tried and nothing same issue. even happens. Even when I'm not using one of the render engine views or workbench. Thanks anyway

Comment: Just tried on my old MacBook which is still using mojave, installed blender 2.92, and no problems.
Must be an issue with the iMac?

Comment: AMD cards have had trouble in the past.  Installing a previous version of the driver may help

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I'll have a try